# Make label tags smaller on screen resize

Tags: html, css

I have some label tags that I'm displaying on my screen and the problem is that when I resize the screen they literally overflow out of the container. My problem is that I want them to resize when the screen gets smaller. So when the screen gets smaller they would also be small too and remain the way they were on my computer screen but in a smaller version of themselves . It's mostly CSS but I couldn't figure it out ( i'm using Bootstrap 5 for this ) .
Here is the code to generate them (the data is coming from an API i'm using VueJS for this )

```
<template>
<div class="d-flex col-12 flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 d-flex bd-highlight col-12" v-for="(question,index) in questions" :key="question +  index">
    <div class="d-flex p-2 me-2" v-for="tag in question.tags" :key ="tag + index">
      <span class="badge bg-dark text-white"><i :class="'devicon-'+tag.nom.toLowerCase()+'-plain'"></i>  {{tag.nom}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Here is the rendering I get for a computer screen .
[Tags on computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKs9J.png)

Here is the rendering I get for a smaller device .
[Tags on resized screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQElC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case for `flex-wrap`. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap):

> The flex-wrap CSS property sets whether flex items are forced onto one line or can wrap onto multiple lines. If wrapping is allowed, it sets the direction that lines are stacked.

Since you're using Bootstrap 5, you can use the class `flex-wrap`. More information can be found on the [Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/?#wrap).

Here's the behavior you're encountering, and the same with `flex-wrap`:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-6 bg-secondary"> 
  <h2>Default<h2>
  <div class="p-2 d-flex bd-highlight col-12">
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-6 bg-primary"> 
  <h2>With flex-wrap class<h2>
  <div class="p-2 d-flex flex-wrap bd-highlight col-12">
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
      <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item</div>
    </div>
</div>
```